# Python Chatterbot efficiency issues

Tags: python, nltk, chatbot

I have made a simple feedback loop program using Chatterbot. The below code takes one to two minutes to respond to itself, and a similar amount of time to load. My question is regarding efficiency - is taking one to two minutes for getting a response normal for chatterbot? If it isn't, how could I improve my efficiency?

Other details - if I don't have the silence performance warning paramater set to true in my chatterbot creation, the following error appears.

> UnsuitableForProductionWarning: The JsonFileStorageAdapter is not
>   recommended for production environments.
>   self.UnsuitableForProductionWarning

This is my code.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

chatterbot = ChatBot("Training Example",silence_performance_warning=True,storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.JsonFileStorageAdapter')
chatterbot.set_trainer(ChatterBotCorpusTrainer)

chatterbot.train(
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings",
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.conversations"
)

print("Ready")
print("1 : How are you?")
response = "How are you?"
first = False

while True:
    response = chatterbot.get_response(str(response))
    if first:
        print("1 : "+str(response))
        first = False
    else:
        print("2 : "+str(response))
        first = True
```

I understand that due to the nature of the bot responding to itself, it shall eventually only output one message repeatedly. This I am not worried about.

Update - the problem resides within visual studio 2015. I have discovered that running my code using the standard IDLE returns the output I expected instantaneously.

Comment: Are you sure there are actually computations going on for one to two minutes between responses (is there significant CPU activity), or is it possible that there is a deliberate waiting instruction (which is set too high)?

Comment: There is significant CPU activity at a constant high level. I have discovered that the root of my problem is confusingly using Python Tools with Visual Studio 2015, as compiling and running my code using IDLE results in no such efficiency issues.

Answer (score 1):

It's nuts to train a model for every request you process. Use a separate script to train and pickle your trained model, then load the pickled model in your interactive script (the one you show us, minus the training) and use it to handle responses.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, there is one to two minutes waiting time for each iteration of the while loop, thus the `chatterbot.get_response` method takes too long.